# next/image Un-configured Host with IP domain

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

i built site using NextJS and image is host at other dev server that run with IP. THe file is public accessible by the image path :
http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/storage/user-profile/61d41e2b05de9_WhatsApp%20Image%202022-01-02%20at%2021.46.03.jpeg
But I receiving the following error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOtVC.png)

I added following code to the next.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080"],
  },
};
```

even tried with

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080"],
  },
};
```

both return the same error as shown in above screenshot

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

domains should not have `http://` or `https://` or the scheme included

You may use the hostname of your source image url

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['cdn.yoursite.com'],
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank Jerson. removing the http & https solved the problem

Comment: It's same if you use an ip addres
just input your ip without any port @user2601660